# Why does C# dynamic resolves internal properties but not methods?

Tags: c#, dynamic

I have a library with the following classes:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    string Foo { get; }
    void Bar(int x);
}

public class EntityFactory 
{
    public static IEntity createEntity() 
    {
        return new Entity();
    }
}

internal class Entity : DynamicObject, IEntity
{
    public void Bar(int x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("inside Bar");
        Console.WriteLine("bar {0}", x);
    }

    public string Foo
    {
        get 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("inside Foo getter");
            return "foo";
        }
    }

    public override bool TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, object[] args, out object result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("inside TryInvokeMember(binder.Name = '{0}')", binder.Name);
        return base.TryInvokeMember(binder, args, out result);
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("inside TryGetMember(binder.Name = '{0}')", binder.Name);
        if (binder.Name == "SomeVar")
        {
            result = 42;
            return true;
        }
        return base.TryGetMember(binder, out result);
    }
}
```

and a program that uses them:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    dynamic entity = EntityFactory.createEntity();
    Console.WriteLine("entity.Foo = {0}", entity.Foo);
    entity.Bar(24);
    Console.WriteLine("entity.SomeVar = {0}", entity.SomeVar);
}
```

The output is

```
inside Foo getter
entity.Foo = foo
inside TryInvokeMember(binder.Name = 'Bar')
inside TryGetMember(binder.Name = 'Bar')
```

and then I receive an exception

```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: `EntityLib.Entity.Bar(int)' is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

Why does the dynamic object accesses property `Foo` directly, but fails to invoke method `Bar` and uses `TryInvokeMember` and `TryGetMember` instead? They have the same access modifiers.

**Update:** The described behavior is observed on Mono. Microsoft fails already when accessing `Foo` property. The following code works as intended:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var entity = EntityFactory.createEntity();
    entity.Bar(24);
    Console.WriteLine("entity.Foo = {0}", entity.Foo);

    dynamic e = entity;
    Console.WriteLine("entity.SomeVar = {0}", e.SomeVar);
}
```

Whether this is a bug or a feature is to be decided by microsoft. However, I would expect that converting variable to dynamic should not restrict the access.

Comment: Because DynamicObject also has TryInvokeMember(), the one you didn't override so can't see being used.

Comment: But I don't want to override it. I want `Bar` to be executed directly. That is why I define it explicitly.

Comment: Updated the question to make it more clear.

Comment: In case of property, it just searches property by name, it does not have to lookup type. In case of method, it can not simply search by name, it has to consider type of parameter as well, so the Binder has different Search logic for it & it could be bug or limitation. You can look into dot peak to see the Source.

Comment: @AkashKava: which class should I decompile with dot peek? what implements dynamic objects?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
 internal class Entity ....
```

The *dynamic* keyword is not a workaround for restricted accessibility.  The Entity class is declared *internal*, so trying to call its Bar() method from code that is not part of the assembly that Entity lives in is going to be rejected by the binder, the message leaves little to the imagination:

> EntityLib.Entity.Bar(int)' is inaccessible due to its protection level

The logical way to get ahead is to declare the Entity class *public*.  If that's a problem for some reason then you can break the rules with Reflection.  You'll need to use BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlag.Instance options in the Type.GetMethod() call.

As to the core question, I'll happily dismiss that as a bug.  The C# DLR binder is impossible to reverse-engineer.  Not in the least because the code for it isn't included in the Reference Source, Microsoft does appear to treat it like a trade secret.  It is.  You can file it at connect.microsoft.com

Comment: In fact I am not trying to break the access rules. The idea is that users must be able to call methods that are declared in the public interface `IEntity` that this class implements. For the rest, the `TryGetMember` and `TryInvokeMember` should be used (even if it is explicitly defined in the `Entity` class). But I guess the implementation doesn't handle such a situation well enough.

Comment: Filed the bug: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/800742/dynamic-keyword-restricts-access-to-members-exposed-via-public-interface