# Compiler says dynamic property is missing but I can see it

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, reflection, metaprogramming

I'm starting to dive into the world of `C# Dynamics and Metaprogramming`, and having some trouble.

I managed to create a `CodeDom` tree, and generate the following code:

```
namespace Mimsy {
    using System;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Collections;

    internal class JubJub {
         private int _wabeCount;
         private ArrayList _updates;

         public JubJub(int wabeCount) {
               this._updates = new ArrayList();
               this.WabeCount = wabeCount;
         }

         public int WabeCount {
               get {
                   return this._wabeCount;
               }
               set {
                   if((value < 0))
                        this._wabeCount = 0;
                   else
                        this._wabeCount = value;
                   this._updates.Add(this._wabeCount);
               }
         }

         public string GetWabeCountHistory() {
               StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
               int ndx;
               for(ndx = 0; (ndx < this._updates.Count); ndx = ndx + 1) {
                     if((ndx == 0))
                            result.AppendFormat("{0}", this._updates[ndx]);
                     else
                            result.AppendFormat(", {0}", this._updates[ndx]);
               }
         }
    }
}
```

I am then compiling dynamically this namespace to an assembly named `"dummy"`.

I can succesfully get an instance of this Type:

```
string typeName = "Mimsy.JubJub";
Type type = dummyAssembly.GetType(typeName);
dynamic obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type, new object[] { 8 });
//obj is a valid instance type
```

If I debug this code, I can see in the debugger that `obj` actually has the property `WabeCount`:

[image: Debugger Information]

However, when trying to access this property, the compiler shouts that the dynamic property does not exist.

[image: Debugger Information 2]

Comment: What is the type of `wabes[ndx]`? Are they `int`?

Comment: They are actually `int` values wrapped as `object`

Comment: Try casting them to `(int)`, like `obj.WabeCount = (int)wabes[ndx]`

Comment: @xanatos I tried casting them, but the problem persists

Comment: Don't use `internal` for the class! `dynamic` probably doesn't like it! Use `public`. And do the casting... (so try `public class`  and `obj.WabeCount = (int)wabes[ndx]`) (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18806787/613130)

Comment: @xanatos That was it!!! The book I am reading used `internal` so I thought it was supposed to work, but now I know not mess with accesors when dealing with `dynamic`. Thank you! (You can post it as an answer so I can vote you)

Comment: I'll write it in the response...

Comment: What book and what example? `internal` means the method is visible *only* to other classes in its assembly. You are calling it from a different assembly.  `dynamic` doesn't allow you to bypass the access specifiers. The book probably called the code in a different way

Comment: The book is `Metaprogramming in .NET` by Kevin Hazzard and Jason Bock. I wasn't aware of `internal` true meaning up until now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are one or perhaps two problems with your code:

- You are using an `internal class`, and trying to access it with `dynamic`. The two things don't play well together. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18806787/613130. Use `public clasas`
- You need to cast the value before assigning it to `wabeCount`, like:

  ```
  obj.WabeCount = (int)wabes[ndx]
  ```

Note that technically, if your "main" assembly is strong named, you could add the `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` to the "dynamic" assembly to make its `internal` "things" visible to the main assembly... I do think it would be wasted work.

Comment: I don't think this is an issue with `dynamic` - you simply can't access an `internal` method from another assembly

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You can if you use reflection. So your sentence isn't an "absolute truth". Simply put, `dynamic` plays with the rules of "standard" .NET resolution (no private access, no internal outside your assembly and so on). This isn't immediately intuitive. The opposite could be true. (and I was surprised when I discovered it, because internally `dynamic` uses reflection to discover things, so it seemed a little strange that it used reflection *but* was less powerful that reflection)

Comment: We are talking about `dynamic`, not Reflection. You can also access private fields using Reflection. `dynamic` isn't Reflection though, and the "bug" isn't really a bug. That's why it was closed as "By Design"

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I haven't spoken of "bug". It is a strange feature. It surely has its reasoning (without even reading the page you haven't linked I can imagine what: `dynamic` "users" don't need `ReflectionPermission`, because they can only use "public" things. Had `dynamic` permitted access to `private`/`protected`/`internal`, "users" would have needed `ReflectionPermission`